# Riemannian metric on polar coordinates.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let a Riemannian manifold $M$, it is possible to write all Riemannian metrics $g$ of manifold $M$ is polar coordinates, if it is possible what guarantees this? To finish, what is the expression general for this metric?

Comment: I am not understand you well. If you mean the global polar coordinates, there is not . But locally, just by Exp , the polar coordinate in $T_xM$ can be pushed to location of $x$.